# Does using Buffer in node js cause memory leak

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I read "Buffer object in node js  is created outside v8 heap"

Is this true?
If yes does it get garbage collected in normal GC cycle?

Answer (score 2):

[Another Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36817641/node-js-buffer-garbage-collection) on Buffer's `#slice` reads

> What this means is that the entire chunk of memory won't be available for garbage collection until all references ... are gone.